# Support for Dynamic path in URL with Nginx and Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, nginx, url-routing

**The use case I am trying to implement.**
Display different content based on the {{random_string}} in the URL path.
Users will see different content based on the {{random_string}} that the URL contains.

eg:

```
www.example.com/{{random_string}}/index.jsp
```

The URLS will look like these below. (
They include random characters before the JSP)

> www.example.com/xc/index.jsp
>   www.example.com/2b/index.jsp
>   www.example.com/43/index.jsp

**My question**

1. How do I setup nginx and tomcat to be able to support the {{random_string}} in the URL without throwing 404?

**My Current Environment/Setup (this works fine)**

Nginx along with Tomcat.
Requests that come to nginx are then redirected to tomcat to access ROOT.war
e,g -  www.example.com/index.jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to change anything in Nginx or Tomcat config. What you could do is to create a servlet that will intercept the requests and extract the {{random_string}} before forwarding to the JSP. Here are the basic steps:

1) Create a servlet with a URL pattern of `/*` so that all requests go to it.

2) In the servlet's `doGet()` method, use `request.getPathInfo()` to retrieve the URL path and parse it to extract the {{random_string}}.

3) Use `request.setAttribute()` to set attributes for the data you want to display in the JSP page.

4) Forward the request to the JSP using a RequestDispatcher, e.g.:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");  
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

5) In the JSP, use the request attributes that you have set in step 3 to display the content.